# setInterval срабатывает позже на время обработки функции в нем. nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

```
let lastLoop = null;
function loop() {
  setInterval(function () {
    const currentLoopTime = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(currentLoopTime-lastLoop); //результат от 105мс до 140мс
    lastLoop = currentLoopTime;
    someFunction();//длительность функции 5-40мс
  }, 100);
}
```

В документации указано, что в setInterval время работы функции никак не учитывается, оно «съедает» часть интервала.

Получается если обработка функции занимает меньше времени чем время интерва, то вызов каждого лупа будет приблизительно ровняться времени самого интервала (100мс +-2).

Почему в данном примере функция setInterval срабатывает каждые 105-140мс,а не 100?

Comment: Сформулируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Так работает Event loop. Время, которое вы передаёте в setInterval / setTimeout, означает, что функция отработает не менее чем через этот промежуток времени.

Если очень коротко объяснять, то каждый тик Event Loop в ноде состоит из нескольких очередей. Вначале запускаются как раз функции из setTimeot/ setinterval, потом обработчики IO (сеть, чтение), потом основной код и потом функции из setImmediate. Также, после каждой стадии запускаются process.nextTick. Задержка обусловлена ожиданием отработки функций из предыдущих стадий.

Есть множество статей по поводу работы Event loop, почитатей, это на самом деле интересно.

Comment: Выходит, javascript от nodejs в этом плане отличается? И интервал всегда будет больше на время обработки функции?

Comment: И лучшим решением для моей задачи будет вызывать setTimeout и указывать туда разницу времени желаемого интервала и время для обработки функции?

Comment: @Iryna, задачу Вы не описали... а в общем, лучшим решением будет _не выполнять каждые 100мс код, выполняющийся до 40мс_. Советую пересмотреть алгоритм. Если же действительно необходимы столь частые тяжелые вычисления - разумно реализовать их нативным кодом (тем самым сократив время выполнения, и нагрузку на аппаратную часть).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function someFunction() {
  const start = new Date().getTime();
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    sum = sum + Math.sin(i);
  console.log("long function", new Date().getTime() - start);
  return sum;
}

let lastLoop = null;
function loop() {
  setInterval(function () {
    const currentLoopTime = new Date().getTime();
    console.log("interval", currentLoopTime-lastLoop); 
    lastLoop = currentLoopTime;
    someFunction();//длительность функции ~100мс
  }, 500);
}

loop();
//someFunction();
```

Comment: удалил свою функцию из лупа всунул Вашу, результат тот же.

Comment: @Iryna Пардон, упустил node.js.